# Vuejs 2.0: How to access vm instance within hook functions in custom directives?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vuejs 1.0 it was able to access vue instance from `this.vm` but i couldn't find a way to do that in vue 2.0.

I'm actually trying to write a custom directive to update bound data when an element is changed by a jquery plugin that doesn't trigger any update in `v-model`.

```
`<input id="dayparting_switch" 
  v-model="options.dayparting" 
  v-observe="options.dayparting" 
  :cheked="options.dayparting" 
data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">`
```

```js
Vue.directive('observe', {
    bind(el, args) {
        var vm = this.vm;
        $(el).change(function() {
            vm.$data = 'changed';
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see you want access the component in which your directive is rendered.

```js
Vue.directive('observe', {
  // in the bind function, the 3rd argument is vnode (the VDOM) created by Vue.
  bind(el, bindings, vnode) {
   // vnode.context is the scope where the directive is rendered.
   const vm = vnode.context 
   $(el).change(function() {
     vm.$data = 'changed';
   });
  }
});
```

Check this line in the source code [VNode context](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js#L10).